# Is there a modbus rtu tester for Raspberry PI?

Tags: raspbian, modbus

I need a tester much like [modpoll](http://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html) but one that runs on Raspbian OS. I need to check if my Raspberry Pi is able to communicate with my modbus slaves.

Comment: I believe source is available in the zip file. You can compile it on Rpi and run it.

Comment: Looks like, modpoll requires some licenced hpp files to compile from the source. You can use libmodbus or something similar (pymodbus on python) to test communication.

Comment: @dastaan I tried pymodbus and other libraries but none of them worked. Thats why I was searching for something that I can directly run on Rpi to check if anything is wrong with hardware...

Comment: I regularly use `libmodbus` on my Rpi without any problem. Use this wiki post, https://github.com/stephane/libmodbus/wiki/Libmodbus-on-Raspberry-pi for step by step guide, how to install libmodbus and then go through test programs. Hope it helps.

Comment: @dastaan I have been trying to make it work on Rpi for weeks now. Are there any configurations that need to be done on RPi? I'll go through the above link.

Comment: Which port are you using for RTU ? Default Rpi (ie, `/dev/ttyAMA0`) or using off the usb to serial converter (ie, `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyACM0`) ? If you're using `ttyAMA0`, make sure to turn off serial console on raspbian which is turned on by default.

Comment: I am using a [rs485 to usb](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B009SIDMNM) converter on port (/dev/ttyUSB0)

Comment: It should be very straight forward in that case. Tell us what you've tried and where you're facing the problem. Show us output / errors that you've encountered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33683/discussion-between-shounak-katyayan-and-dastaan).